# Why do I get "The error occurred while evaluating nil.<=>" when using sort_by?

Tags: ruby, sorting, enumerable

This is the code:

```
xml = REXML::Document.new(data)
  @contacts = Array.new
  xml.elements.each('//entry') do |entry|
    person = {}
    person['name'] = entry.elements['title'].text

    gd_email = entry.elements['gd:email']
    person['email'] = gd_email.attributes['address'] if gd_email

    @contacts << person
  end

  @contacts.sort_by { |k| k['name'] } if @contacts[0].size > 0
```

the error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<=>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
person['name'] = entry.elements['title'].text || ''
```

instead of:

```
person['name'] = entry.elements['title'].text
```

Comment: @rtacconi `#sort_by` doesn't sort the array in place, but rather returns a new array that is sorted. Perhaps you meant `@contacts = @contacts.sort_by...`

Comment: Yes, you need to, in general, suffix [array methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002185) with a '!' for them to modify the current array.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't the last line be

```
@contacts.sort_by { |k| k['name'] } if @contacts.size > 0
```

not `@contacts[0].size` ?

Also, try adding a `@contacts.compact!` before sorting to ensure you have no `nil` values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can streamline your code a bit:

```
@contacts = Array.new
xml = REXML::Document.new(data)
xml.elements.each('//entry') do |entry|
  gd_email = entry.elements['gd:email']

  @contacts << {
    'name'  => entry.elements['title'].text,
    'email' => (gd_email) ? gd_email.attributes['address'] : '' 
  }
end

@contacts.sort_by! { |k| k['name'] }
```

I don't have samples of your XML to test it, but it looks like it should work.

If the `element['title']` is null you'll get the error you are seeing so you'll want to either skip those elements or use a default value for the name field, like "unknown".